# Java: array initialize in shorthand cannot assign to an object

Tags: java, arrays, initialization

```
Integer i1 = 1;
Integer i2 = 2;

Number arr1[] = {i1, i2};
```

as we already know, {i1, i2} is shorthand for new Number[]{i1, i2}

but when declare in this way:

```
Object o = {i1, i2};   //error
```

I got a compile error:
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer[] to Object

On the other hand,

```
Object arr1 = new Number[]{i1, i2};
```

Isn't it means, that the array can be convert to Object.

And if I write in this way:

```
Number arr2[] = {i1, i2};
Object obj = arr2;
```

It's also okay.

So, the problem i want to consult is, why did I got the compile error. 
***Or the eclipse gave me an mistake error message*** ,for '{i1, i2}' in the expression 'Object o = {i1, i2};' is not an array?

Comment: `Object arr1 = new int[] { 1, 2 };` - every type of array (even primitive arrays) **is-a** `Object`). See also, the methods in [`java.lang.reflect.Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html).

Comment: I wonder why you get *"Type mismatch: cannot convert from Integer[] to Object"* while I get *"error: illegal initializer for Object"*.

Comment: @Gendarme I get OP's error in Eclipse. Not that it makes much sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shorthand array initializers are only valid when initializing an *array*. `Number arr1[] = {i1, i2};` declares and initializes an **array** of `Number`. `Object o` just declares a single object, not an array. You could write `Object o = new Number[] { i1, i2 };` (e.g., not shorthand) and it would work.

Comment: En, I did also think Eclipse gave me a mistake message, for it is not an array. But I not sure. Thanks!

Comment: The eclipse show me "cannot convert from Integer[] to Object", but it is not an array here.

Comment: @JackyMao: **If** Eclipse is saying that, it's wrong. You can convert from `Integer[]` to `Object`. You just can't initialize an `Object` with an array initializer.

Answer (score 2):

`{..}` is a syntactic sugar for declaring an array type and initializing it.

In your `Object o = {i1, i2}`, you didn't specify that it is an array type (because you omitted `[]`), so the compiler does not even know that it is an array i.e. it treats that it is a single object and throws error.

```
Object o = {i1, i2}; // This is NOT an array type

Object[] o = {i1, i2}; //This represents an array
```

But, **once you have got an array object created** (i.e., either with `new` operator specifying the size or by using the above syntactic sugar), you will have an array object which you can assign it to an `Object` type as shown below:

```
Number arr1[] = {i1, i2};//arr1 created & initialized
Object obj1 = arr1;//arr1 can now be assigned to Object type

Number arr2[] = new Number[2];//arr2 created (initialized values to null)
Object obj2 = arr2;//arr2 can now be assigned to Object type
```

Comment: The main idea is similar to Crowder. Thank U!